# Continue statement in If Else condition gives infinite loop

Tags: c, arrays, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was solving a problem on strings

Given a string S, write a program to title case every first letter of words in string.

Input:
The first line consists of an integer T i.e number of test cases. T testcases follow. The first and only line of each test case consists of a string S.

Output:
For each testcase, in a new line, print the required output.

Constraints: 
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= |S| <= 1000

Example:
Input:
1
I love programming
Output:
I Love Programming

and for that I came up with this solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    //code
    int t,flag;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
        int n,i=0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        char str[100];
        scanf("%s", str);

        while(i<n){
            if (str[i]!= str[n-1-i]){
             flag = 1;  
            printf("%d", flag);
            break;
            }
            else{
            flag = 0;
           printf("%d", flag);
            continue;
            }
            i++;
    }
    if(flag ==1 )
    printf("No\n");
    else
    printf("Yes\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine when continue is removed, but when the above code is run, it prints 0 infinitly. 
Can you help me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) **indent/format code for clarity and visualization of the program flow**; 2) the "infinite loop" is due to a `while` and not breaking out of it correctly (the if/else might be the keys to existing the loop, but cannot cause a loop construct themselves, and if/then *do not* affect the 'scope' of a continue).

Comment: Anyway, by following #1, the *issue* should be clearly apparent. (Hint: the loop termination condition is never met for `i<n` if/when neither `i` or `n` change.)

Comment: More meaningful variable names would be helpful

Comment: You need to [learn how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "continue" here means "immediately perform the next iteration in the current loop, in this case the while loop".

In your code the line "i++" is therefor not executed and variable i never changes, thus causing an infinite loop.